# Limit Entries in a Range of Cells - Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel Worksheet (.xlsx) I'm trying to determine if I can limit an entry in a range of fice cells within a single row to just one entry.  In other words, I'm working with cell B1, B2, B3, B4, and B5.  I'm entering an X in the cell based on the header designations.  I only want the spreadsheet to allow one X to be entered in that range of cells.  So as an example, if an X is entered in cell B2, and I then type X in cell B4, I would either receive an error message or the X in cell B2 would be automatically deleted.  Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so, how to set it up?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Why don't you instead of allowing a value in B1, B2, B3, B4 or B5, ask on cell B1 the option and let it be chosen with a combobox

Answer (score 0):

Select B1:B5 and use Data Validation, Custom and write the following:
`=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5,"X")=1`
In this case you can write X only once
When you try the second time a message will appear Retry, Cancel, Help
But to move X to the last place you will need VBA
To write X in another Cell you have to delete X from the first cell

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is by using data validation with list and write the following in cell `B1`:

```
=IF(AND(B2="",B3="",B4="",B5=""),cross)
```

This can then be added to the rest of the cells from `B2` to `B5` with the cell references changed for each (to remove the cell that you are currently on and add the other is the range).

Then in another column (can be on another sheet to hide it), leave a blank cell and put an X in the cell below. Then select the **Formulas** tab, and **Name Manager**, then select **New...**. In there input Name: cross and under Reference: select those 2 cells.

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but this makes it so that you can't even try to put in other values.

Comment: I don’t understand. (1) What, exactly, is your `IF` formula supposed to be doing?  (2) What good does it do to pre-fill the cells with formulas if the user can overwrite those formulas and insert data into the cells?